# Single variable analysis without Euclidean metric?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

So, I was thinking, suppose we re-interpreted whole of analysis (say from the epsilon delta definition of limit) where we took the distance between two points as some general metric instead of the Euclidean distance, would there be any interesting/significant type of analysis which comes out?

I'm looking for a survey type answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is and it is the study of [metric space analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) (or look at [here](https://www.geneseo.edu/%7Eaguilar/public/notes/Real-Analysis-HTML/ch9-metric-spaces.html) for a detailed discussion).

As you will realize going through the links, it is a whole subject where some properties are preserved, while others are not (like, for example, the Heine Borel theorem: it is not granted anymore that with a non-euclidean metric closed and bounded sets are compact).